# How to go from numpy 3d mgrid to position array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to generate a multi variate gaussian that will give me an output based on 3 coordinates, x,y and z. I want each coordinate to take on a value between `0` and `199` inclusive.

I am not sure how to go from `x`, `y` and `z` as Ive got defined below, to an array size 200^3 x 3, which contains all the positions or coordinates xyz.

I need an array of positions so that I can pass it as a parameter for the scipy `multivariate_normal.pdf` function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

x, y, z= np.mgrid[0:200,0:200,0:200]

mu = np.array([100,100,100])
covar = np.array([[100,0,0],[0,100,0],[0,0,100]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out numpy as a function called `vstack` which does the job.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

x,y,z = np.mgrid[0:200,0:200,0:200]

xyz = np.vstack((x.flat,y.flat,z.flat)).T

mu = np.array([100,100,100])
covar = np.array([[100000,0,0],[0,100000,0],[0,0,100000]])

pdf = multivariate_normal.pdf(xyz,mu,covar)

pdf = pdf.reshape(200,200,200)
```